# Eclipse color theme Unhandled event loop exception java.lang.StackOverflowError

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I tried color theme,when I click any theme,I get this:

[image: StackOverFlowError]

How can I solved this problem?
I tried uninstall and re-install this plugin.But still doesn't work.

Comment: And what plugin is that then? And what release of Eclipse?

Comment: I use eclipse luna.plugin is eclipse-color-theme 0.14.I install on eclipse marketplace.I tried re-install, but doesn't work